# Search for text and check for underline

Tags: vba, ms-word

How can i search for text and check the same text for underline in the word document.
Can anyone help me out??

```
Sub Underline()
    Dim fnd As String
    Dim n As Long

    fnd = InputBox("Enter text to search" & vbCr & vbCr _
    & "Click OK to search the entire workbook for all instances of the search text.")

    Dim x As Integer

    x = 0

    Do While x = 0
        With Selection.Find
            .ClearFormatting
        End With

        If fnd = False Then
            x = 1
            Exit Do
        End If
        Selection.Find.Execute
        If .Underline = False Then
            Selection.Comments.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Text:="pls underline text"
            Selection.Find.Execute
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Sub Underline()
Dim fnd As String
Dim n As Long
fnd = InputBox("Enter text to search" & vbCr & vbCr _
       & "Click OK to search the entire workbook for all instances of the search text.")

Dim x As Integer
x = 0
Do While x = 0
With Selection.Find
.ClearFormatting

End With
If fnd = False Then
x = 1
Exit Do
End If
Selection.Find.Execute
If .Underline = False Then
Selection.Comments.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Text:="pls underline text"
Selection.Find.Execute

End If
Loop

End Sub

Comment: this is not working..can u give me an alternative

Comment: @brettdj can u suggest me a method

Comment: @user1553562: Please update the code in your question above. It is very difficult to read it in the comment.

Comment: @SiddharthRout can u suggest me some method...that is not working..>Im not able to format that...

Comment: Can you not edit your question and paste the code there?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim fnd As String

    fnd = InputBox("Enter text to search" & vbCr & vbCr _
    & "Click OK to search the entire document for all instances of the search text.")

    If fnd = "" Then Exit Sub

    Set c = ActiveDocument.Content

    c.Find.ClearFormatting
    c.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With c.Find
        .Text = fnd
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
    End With

    c.Find.Execute
    While c.Find.Found
        If c.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineNone Then
            c.Select
            c.Comments.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Text:="pls underline text"
        End If
        c.Find.Execute
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: :- this runs fine...but it also comments the underlined text too....how to overcome that

Answer (score -1):

comment the below line in code from Siddharth Rout

c.Comments.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Text:="pls underline text"