# Word VBA: Moving textstring from the end of a paragraph to the beginning of the paragraph

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm new to VBA. I have several long documents where a citation or a document number appears at the end of a paragraph. Luckily, these citations and document are enclosed in parentheses, which should make it easy to isolate. I need to move the content of those parentheses (including the parentheses themselves) to the front of each paragraph and then add two spaces after the closing parenthesis.

For example:

> This is my text in Paragraph 1. (http://nytimes.com)
>
> This is my text in Paragraph 2. (1.b.3B)

Should look like:

> (http://nytimes.com)  This is my text in Paragraph 1.
>
> (1.b.3B)  This is my text in Paragraph 2.

I found the answer in the following link useful, but can't seem to apply it to my case: [Get paragraph no where txt is found, and move text to end of paragraph using Word 2010 vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597775/get-paragraph-no-where-txt-is-found-and-move-text-to-end-of-paragraph-using-wor)

Many thanks in advance.

Here's what I have up to now, but the script just doesn't seem to run:

```
Sub Test1()

Dim currDoc As Document
Set currDoc = ActiveDocument
Dim docRng As Range, currRng As Range, strRng As Range
Set docRng = ActiveDocument.Content
Dim currPara As Paragraph
Dim strText As String

Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory ' Start from the beginning of the doc.

For Each currPara In docRng.Paragraphs ' Loop through the paragraphs in the active document.

Set currRng = currDoc.Range(currPara.Range.Start, currPara.Range.End) ' Selects the current paragraph, so that the search is conducted paragraph by paragraph.

With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "\(*\)"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
End With

If currRng.Find.Execute Then

With Selection
    .Select
    .Cut
    .StartOf Unit:=wdParagraph
    .Paste
    .InsertAfter "  "
End With

End If

Next currPara

End Sub
```

Comment: can you add to your question any single paragraph of the document presenting **what is** >> **what should be**. Could be easier to help you.

Comment: Absolutely. I've added it above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close to correct solution to move simple text. But, what I realised, it was a problem to move hyperlinks as syntax `"\(*\)"` didn't recognise hyperlinks. Therefore I put some additional small modifications. That works for me in Word 2010:

```
Sub Test1_Tested_incl_Hyper()

Dim currDoc As Document
Set currDoc = ActiveDocument
Dim docRng As Range, currRng As Range, strRng As Range
Set docRng = ActiveDocument.Content
Dim currPara As Paragraph
Dim strText As String

Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory ' Start from the beginning of the doc.

For Each currPara In docRng.Paragraphs ' Loop through the paragraphs in the active document.

Set currRng = currDoc.Range(currPara.Range.Start, currPara.Range.End) ' Selects the current paragraph, so that the search is conducted paragraph by paragraph.
currRng.Select
With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = "\("
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = True
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
End With

If Selection.Find.Found Then

With currDoc.Range(Selection.Range.Start, currPara.Range.End - 1)
    .Select
    .Cut
    .StartOf Unit:=wdParagraph
    .Paste
    .InsertAfter "  "
End With

End If

Next currPara

End Sub
```

**EDIT- code for footers**

```
Sub Test1_for_Footers()

Dim currDoc As Document
Set currDoc = ActiveDocument
Dim docRng As Range, currRng As Range, strRng As Range
Set docRng = ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdPrimaryFooterStory)
Dim currPara As Paragraph
Dim strText As String

For Each currPara In docRng.Paragraphs

currPara.Range.Select
With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = "\("
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = True
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
End With

If Selection.Find.Found Then
Selection.Extend ")"

With Selection
    .Select
    .Cut
    .StartOf Unit:=wdParagraph
    .Paste
    .InsertAfter "  "
End With

End If

Next currPara

End Sub
```

Comment: This is terrific! Thank you!

Comment: One additional question: the script doesn't seem to go into the footnotes. Is that because of the docRng setting? Is there a way to have the script also run in footnotes?

Comment: Yes, exactly. `ActiveDocument.Content` is the main text of the document. To make changes in other parts of document you need to refer to other StoryRanges, eg. `Set docRng = ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdPrimaryFooterStory)`. See new set of code for you.