# How to find a specific word in a word document and paste a word near to that using vba code?

Tags: vba

Can any one please tell, How to find a specific word in a word document and paste a word near to that using vba code?

I have already opened the document.So i just want to find the word and paste a word near to that. I have done this using movedown and moveright methods to go to that specific word.But it is more dependent on the position of cursor.

Thanks,

Bharathi

Comment: Did you using `Find` and record a macro?

Comment: Try to review [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15937428/2143262) where some text is searched and moved. I think you could quite easily adjust it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I use this in access I don't know if it will work for you.

```
Dim mWord As Word.Application
Dim mDoc As Word.Document
Dim mRange As Word.Range

Set mDoc = mWord.Documents.Open("YourPath")
mDoc.SaveAs "Where you want to save"

Set mWord = New Word.Application
mWord.Visible = False

DoEvents
Set mRange = mWord.ActiveDocument.Content

mRange.Find.Execute FindText:=TextToFind1, ReplaceWith:=TextToFind1 & TextToReplace1, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
mRange.Find.Execute FindText:="TextToFind2", ReplaceWith:="TextToReplace2", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Set mRange = Nothing

mDoc.Save

'Display
mWord.Visible = True

Shell "Explorer.exe /n,/e," & "DirectoryToOpen", vbNormalFocus
```

Good luck

Comment: Hi FrankMatis,
Thanks for your reply. Actually, i have to find the word and paste a word next to that and i dont want to replace that. Can you please suggest me some other way to done with that?

Comment: Well you could search for a word and replace the word and add what you want to add. I changed my answer to work better with your problem. (Is it your problem or you're problem I'm not really good in english.)

Comment: Hi Frank,
Thank you.I will try with this.

Comment: if i am your problem..i m sorry :)
-Bharathi